# Assembly local variable and parameters

Tags: c, assembly

I have the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int adunare(int a,int b)
{
  int c=3;
  int d=6;

  while(c>10) c++;
  if(c>15) return a+b+c+d;
  else return a+b+c-d;
}

int main()
{
  int w=5;
  int y=6;
  printf("%d",adunare(w,y));
}
```

My question is in assembly it puts the variable w,y at the [esp+24] ,[esp+28].

Why it puts my variables there?

I know that local variables are always [ebp-....].

Why here it is not [ebp-..]?

Comment: there is no requirement for C to even have a "stack" so if it does, the detail is implementation specific. If there is a user stack which is also the same stack as the hardware stack, so long as the local variables are not in damage from function calls or interrupts, they are safe. Whether they are indexed by a negative offset from `ebp` or a positive offest from `esp` is just the implementation's convention.

Comment: In extreme case the variable can be removed completely (if it's usage doesn't have any effect on other things, like `for (size_t i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i) {}` will be removed completely by optimizer, thus `i` doesn't exist anywhere except source. Still the binary is valid (by C++ language definition).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know that local variables are always [ebp-....]

They're not (as evidenced by your question too, I suppose).

It's legal for a compiler to compile really naively, always using a frame pointers (even in functions that don't do variable-size stack allocations) and always putting locals on the stack in the first place (which is definitely not a rule). In a first year course in university, it is sometimes pretended that that's normal, to keep things simple.

Not using a frame pointer is usually possible, it works mostly the same as if you had used one except that offsets are calculated relative to the stack pointer, which you are now only allowed to move in predictable ways. Because it has to be predictable (that is, every instructions that references a stack slot can use a constant offset to do so), this optimization cannot be used in functions that use `alloca` or VLAs. In your example function neither are used, so no frame pointer is necessary.

Also in general you should *not* expect local variables to correspond to specific stack slots in the first place, regardless of how they are addressed. It is allowed, common, and often a good thing, to keep a variable in a register over the entire lifetime of the variable. Especially if that life time is short or if the usage-density is very high. On top of that, variables with non-overlapping life times can (and should, because it reduces the stack size) share stack slots, since it would be the case that at most one of them needs storage at any one moment (thanks to the assumption of non-overlapping life times).

It's also allowed to have a variable hop from one stack slot to an other, this might happen when you swap two variables in a way that allows the swap to be resolved "virtually", by just changing which stack slot the variables live in and not actually exchanging the data.

Comment: @user6575913 sure, if that's what you want to call it

Comment: ok.thx for clarification. i just started study this (a security course) and i am willing to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably a compiler optimization. The variables aren't used within `main` scope so are placed directly on the stack, ready for the function call.

Comment: but in theory it is like i said,no?

Comment: @user6575913 - I'm not certain but I believe there's no definition of how code should be compiled, only how it should "behave". Obviously different platforms have different compilations.